# Find all substrings of a given string recursively in python

Tags: python, string, function, recursion, substring

Given string "lion" is should get the following output of substrings,
["ion", "lin", "in", "io", "li", "on", "lion"]

This is what i have so far,

```
def Substring(n):
   sub = [n]
   if len(n) > 2:
       sub.extend(Substring(n[1:]))
       sub.extend(Substring(n[:-1]))
   return list(sub)
```

my current output is ['lion', 'ion', 'on', 'io', 'lio', 'io', 'li']

I'm missing substrings "lin" and "in" and I shouldn't have "lio".

I haven't been able to figure it if I need a different method or if I need additional statements?

Comment: Why is `lio` not valid?

Comment: Why is there no "lon" in the output? And what about "lo" and "ln"?

Comment: lion has no substring lin or in or lon. It is not a substring it is a combination

Comment: I wrote an answer assuming this was just "all possible substrings" without reading carefully enough... is your assignment to figure out what the actual algorithm is, or have you just not given us the full text of the assignment?

Comment: The assignment is to write a function the takes a string argument and returns substrings. "lo" is not counted since there is no path of subwords from lion to lo.

Comment: If that's the case, both answers are correct (I've undeleted mine), and your question seems to have at least one issue. Your example correct output should not contain "lin" or "in", as those are not substrings of "lion". You should also make it clear that recursion is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

There's a one-liner for this that doesn't require `itertools`. Depending on what you're used to, it may be more or less legible.

```
tuple(s[i:i+j+1] for i in range(len(s)) for j in range(len(s)-i))
# ('l', 'li', 'lio', 'lion', 'i', 'io', 'ion', 'o', 'on', 'n')
```

Note that the `tuple` cast is only for printing; without it, Python will give you a generator, which is much more efficient if you're iterating over it.

For substrings of length 2 or greater:

```
tuple(s[i:i+j+1] for i in range(len(s)) for j in range(1, len(s)-i))
# ('li', 'lio', 'lion', 'io', 'ion', 'on')
```